# Java JPA LazyInitializationException when trying to create a new object and add it to Arraylist

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a Java spring JPA application which has a `Bord` entity and a `BordRow` entity. A `Bord` has multiple `BordRows`. Now I tried to create a new `BordRow` and add it to the list of `BordRows` in `Bord`. However, I get a LazyInitializationException. How do I have to change my code to create a new `BordRow`, save it in the database and return the whole `Bord` object?
The parameter `content` is something like: `{title: "Test Row", bord_id: 1}`

Exception:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: Bord.rows, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:606) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.write(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:409) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.add(PersistentBag.java:383) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at WebSocketController.create(WebSocketController.java:47) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:565) [spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:511) [spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:94) [spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:520) [spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:454) [spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:144) [spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_221]
```

Bord class:

```
@Table(name = "bords")
@Entity
public class Bord
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String icon;

    @Column
    private String background;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bord", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<BordRow> rows;

    public Bord()
    {
        rows = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addRow(BordRow row)
    {
        this.rows.add(row);
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

BordRow class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bord_rows")
public class BordRow
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bord_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Bord bord;

    public BordRow(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

WebsocketController method:

```
@MessageMapping("/bord_row/create")
@SendTo("/bord_row/created")
public Optional<Bord> create(String content) {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(content);
    Optional<Bord> bord = bordRepository.findById(object.getInt("bord_id"));

    if(bord.isPresent())
    {
        BordRow row = new BordRow(object.getString("title"));
        row.setBord(bord.get());
        List<BordRow> rows = bord.get().getRows();
        rows.add(row);
        bord.get().setRows(rows);
        bordRepository.save(bord.get());
    }

    return bord;
}
```

WebsocketController method other try:

```
@MessageMapping("/bord_row/create")
@SendTo("/bord_row/created")
public Optional<Bord> create(String content) {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(content);
    Optional<Bord> bord = bordRepository.findById(object.getInt("bord_id"));

    if(bord.isPresent())
    {
        BordRow row = new BordRow(object.getString("title"));
        row.setBord(bord.get());
        bord.get().addRow(row);
        bordRepository.save(bord.get());
    }

    return bord;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you load an object from the database

Optional bord = bordRepository.findById(object.getInt("bord_id"))

The list with BoardRows is lazy loaded which means as soon as the transaction is closed you will work on a proxy. This is the error you got, because you want to add something on the proxy.

You can Chance the lazy loading to an eager loading which is nor recomanded, because of performance reasons.
You could use EntityGraphs. Those allows you to load deeper objects even if they are lazy loaded.

I hope this help

Matthias